# Oxford/Cambridge Sanskrit Book

Tags: resource-request, sanskrit

A few years ago I came across a book on Sanskrit (not a dictionary, not a grammar book, not a book on Sanskrit literature( that belonged to the "Classical Language Series" from either Oxford or Cambridge -- about a 1000 pages. The book looked at the history of how the language developed from proto-indo-european and also included words borrowed from Tamil and Kannada into Sanskrit at Vedic times (shows those other languages were equally ancient). I later came across it in google scholar or other service that digitized the book and made it available to the public. I am trying to find this book. Can you help?

Comment: MIght it be T. Burrow, The Sanskrit Language? The copies I can find on line are Faber & Faber, and reprinted by an Indian publisher; but my memory is that it was part of a series. (My copy is still in a box somewhere, I think).

Comment: Burrow's book is a classic, still very useful. (But he did not accept the laryngeal theory.)

Comment: I've now found my copy of Burrow. It's part of a series indeed, but it's _The Great Languages_, from Faber & Faber, not a "Classical Language" series from either Oxford or Cambridge, so it may not be what you were looking for.

Comment: OMG! This IS the book I have been searching for many many years! Thank you so much! I see many sources of digital copies of the book and will look for a physical copy too! Thanks again!

Comment: @ColinFine Could you pl. post your comment as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like Burrow, *The Sanskrit Language*: it is part of a series *The Great Languages* from Faber & Faber, not from Oxford or Cambridge.